# Height difference in multicolum list

Tags: html, css, height, multiple-columns

I have created multi colum list. In each list there is a  div inside it. Since the height of this added div, the a blank space is appearing in between this and next row. Is der any way to expand this row to fill up the blank space or to bring up the next row.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
        <div class="exp">abc abc</div></li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Problem explained here http://jsfiddle.net/DPRtF/18/ (See between 3 and 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Masonry might be what you want, then: http://masonry.desandro.com/ It solves the floating-divs-don't-have-balanced-height problem.

Comment: working. but, the div.exp is hidden on page load. when i expands this overlaps to li below. if div is not hidden no problems.

Comment: When you expand the div, you can call `.masonry('reload')`, which will resize accordingly.

Comment: What does the css look like for your div?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for I think you need some javascript.

What I did here was putting together a small script that loops thru all the boxes and finds the largest one and then adds that height to all the boxes. This way the blank space disappears.

The code needs some cleaning up, but it proves the point.

http://jsfiddle.net/E2K8c/

```
var highestBox = jQuery('li:first');
jQuery('li').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).height() > highestBox.height())
        highestBox = jQuery(this);
});
jQuery('li').height(highestBox.height());
```

Comment: no don't need to increase height for all columns. I need to increase height of that particular <li> so that the border line is aligned.

Comment: I was thinking that the layout was flexible. If it's not maybe you could check all the boxes that are in the same vertical position as the box that is too high?

Comment: You should be able to use a bit of the code I wrote. But you would want to check the vertical position of each box. That way you would know if they are on the same line or not.